# Spring Cloud Gateway hides server websocket handshake 401 failures to clients

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty

I'm reverse proxying a websocket backend API with spring-cloud-gateway 2.2.3. When this backend API rejects some websocket handshake request with a `401 Unauthorized` status response, then spring-cloud-gateway still returns a 101 handshake status to the client (which gets confused and then misbehaves)

I need spring-cloud-gateway to return the original 401 websocket handshake error to the client so the SCG reverse proxy is transparent to the client (which is conforming to the [WebSocket specs handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4.2.2))

Here are the full [wiretap traces and exception](https://gist.github.com/gberche-orange/854118a9a714bb639449767aebeace06) (I have redacted hostnames).

The client-side response in this WSS request is available as a [HAR file](https://gist.github.com/gberche-orange/56aa7ebea8550a4b5edb27c7bf0cd179) captured from chrome and which displays in chrome
[as this screenpshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYITC.png).

Here is my spring cloud gateway configuration

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: route_shield
          uri: https://shield-webui-cf-mysql.nd-int-cfapi.was.redacted
          predicates:
            - Host=**
          filters:
            - SetRequestHostHeader=shield-webui-cf-mysql.nd-int-cfapi.was.redacted

        ssl:
          useInsecureTrustManager: true
```

I'm wondering whether this is a spring-cloud-gateway bug, or a desired behavior which I can override.

To override it, here are alternatives I'm considering:

- using [circuit breaker filter and fallback](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#fallback-headers) to a local handler returning a 401
- write a [custom post-filter](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#writing-custom-gatewayfilter-factories)

  - Override/patch the [WebsocketRoutingFilter](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/ac5037d0a9aaf5421e77a672b1c619dd2199d8a9/spring-cloud-gateway-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter/WebsocketRoutingFilter.java#L182-L195)

    - However my debugger breakpoint in the `handle(WebSocketSession session)` method does not trigger, suspecting it is not called
    - Likely would need to provide a `RequestUpgradeStrategy` bean as an alternative to the default implementation of org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.server.upgrade.ReactorNettyRequestUpgradeStrategy#getNativeResponse mentionned in the trace

```
io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketHandshakeException: Invalid handshake response getStatus: 401 Unauthorized
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketClientHandshaker13.verify(WebSocketClientHandshaker13.java:274) ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ http://localhost:8080/v2/events [ReactorNettyRequestUpgradeStrategy]
```

Comment: Very similar to github issue [857 
Gateway fail to close websocket when server return 401 when fail to check token during handshake](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/857) marked as duplicate of [845 Gateway don't close websocket connection when client close websocket](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/845) which is still open from Feb 2019

Comment: Submitted issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/1884 with further possible steps to fix the issue.